# Feasibility/difficulty of implementing legit spyware software for Android

Tags: android

I'm a non-android-programmer who needs to employ/partner with an android developer or development team to implement a project. What I am interested in knowing is how difficult my requirements are likely to be to implement. I have already approached several developers but so far haven't got any answers beyond "sorry we don't have time now" or "we'll get back to you". I believe it would help me to find a developer if someone could give me some indication of how difficult this project will be to implement.

There are two main requirements. Firstly, the software should monitor usage of the device (it will be a tablet computer) so that usage is recorded and regularly transmitted to me (e.g. by automatic email of a datafile). By usage I mean I want to know (a) what apps are installed and when, and (b) what apps are in use (in the foreground) and when. Secondly, the software should be able to restrict usage of the device so that it can be configured to only be able to run certain apps, and only at certain times. At other times it should be unlockable. It doesn't need to be hacker-proof, just child proof.

Skeptics will want to know why I want malicious-sounding spyware written for me: my attentions are good - I'm a child psychologist and we are planning to run a study where we look at how very small children use tablet computers in an ordinary family setting. Basically I will be handing tablets out to parents of three-year-olds: the parents will know exactly what we have done to the tablets.

To avoid asking too vague a question, I guess I could specify even further: is this even possible without a rewrite of the operating system itself (in which case I guess this is a big job), or can this be done more simply? Perhaps there is already software or libraries available which do this?

Comment: You want someone to build you a ROM... you better have a good bit of moolah

Comment: It's doable. Feasibility depends on available resources, as @zgc7009 indicated. Regardless, the question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly it's feasible, and I don't see why it would be as expensive as has been suggested. The key is that you need this only to be *child-proof*: that's far easier than making it hacker-proof.

All you'd need is a system service to log and transmit various events, and a replacement home/launcher app to prevent launch of unwanted apps. Simples.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me... I would have been very surprised if a custom ROM was really necessary!